# How to reverse a recursive call?

Tags: c++, recursion

My task is to write a function that produces the following output:

```
This was written by call number 1.  
This was written by call number 2.  
This was written by call number 3.  
This was written by call number 4.  
This was written by call number 5.  
This was ALSO written by call number 5.  
This was ALSO written by call number 4.  
This was ALSO written by call number 3.  
This was ALSO written by call number 2.  
This was ALSO written by call number 1.
```

This is not limited to the number 5, the program can take any input from the user and it'll output their numbers.

Here's what I have so far:

```
void function_call(int number);
int main(){
    int userInput;
    cout<<"Please enter a digit: ";
    cin>>userInput;

    function_call(userInput);
}

void function_call(int number){
    if (number == 1){
        cout<<"This was written by call number "<<number<<"."<<endl;
    }

    else{

        function_call(number - 1);
        cout<<"This was written by call number "<<number<<"."<<endl;
    }

}
```

My current code outputs the first part, but not the second part where the numbers are decreasing. How do I make it so that the second part of the output is displayed?

Comment: Take a shot at changing the order between the recursive call and the print statement, see what happens.

Comment: Your "This was written by call number 1" is written by the fifth call, not the first. You need to count upwards, so you need two parameters.

Comment: @StoryTeller When I place the print statement on top of the recursive call, it prints the numbers in reverse. But when I place the print statement at the front of the recursive call and at the back, it prints the "This ALSO was written" lines first. I want the numbers incrementing to be the first ones displayed.

Comment: You now have two very big hints on how to accomplish it. Try thinking about it some more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this, when calling `function_call(1,userInput)`:

```
void function_call(int curr,int last)
{
    if (curr <= last)
    {
        cout<<"This was written by call number "<<curr<<"."<<endl;
        function_call(curr+1,last);
        cout<<"This was ALSO written by call number "<<curr<<"."<<endl;
    }
}
```